# File `datatool.sty' not found

Tags: miktex, glossaries, texstudio, datatool

I am making a latex document with class {article}

I want to make a page for glossaries

I added the below in my preamble

```
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{datatool-base}
\usepackage{glossaries}
```

But I am still getting the error

```
File `datatool.sty' not found. \usepackage
```

I am using MiKTeX and TeXstudio.

Can someone please advice what I else needs to be added or changed to make this work?

Comment: Details about your set up are probably worth mentioning... Is it even installed?  I'd first check with `kpsewhich datatool.sty` on my system, which has TeX Live installed.  For MiKTeX, I'm not sure how you look.

Comment: Do you really need `datatool` for `glossaries`? Comment it with `%`.

Comment: @jon it's the same IIRC. You should go ahead and install all packages with the package manager (start menu search it).

Comment: Hi - Thanks a lot for the quick advice. The package was not installed and I totally forgot about MikeTex Package manager. I installed the package and now everything works. I also commented the database-base package.

Comment: `datatool` automatically loads `datatool-base`, so you don't need `\usepackage{datatool-base}` if you already have `\usepackage{datatool}`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a missing package and could be solved by installing this with MiKTeX package manager.